# How to replace and refurbish the EMU suit used at the ISS?

Tags: iss, spacesuits

If new parts for the EMU suits should be transported to the ISS they may use the Progress cargo space ship. But what about return of used suit parts to ground for refurbishment?

A Progress cargo ship may be used to burn up waste in the atmosphere. The [VBK-Raduga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBK-Raduga) capsule was used to return material to the ground but the last flight was 25 years ago.

Is the Soyuz capsule the only possibility to return EMU suit parts to ground?

Answer (score 2):

The SpaceX [Dragon](https://www.spacex.com/dragon) spacecraft has the ability to return 3,000 kg of cargo from ISS to the ground.

Comment: But what was used in the eight years after the retirement of the Shuttle and before the Dragon spacecraft?